# Split array object "1;item1" into 1 and item1

Tags: ios, arrays

```
country = (
        "3;India",
        "4;US",
        "5;UK",
        )

state = (
        "9;3;Uttar Pradesh",
        "10;3;Maharashtra",
        "11;3;Andaman and Nicobar Islands"
        )

city = (
        "110;3;10;pune",
        "111;3;10;mumbai",
        "112;3;10;nasik",
        )
```

I want to show just the country name in `dropdown` list and want to pass it's Id to web service. If user selects India, I have to pass 3. How can I do this?

Comment: can you show the proper array once , reason your array is not clear...

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik now is it ok??

Comment: actually your array given the wrong answer , how can I get 3;India , can u add some more code related to this

Comment: in dropdown list if i select 1st item means country[0] it will display 3;India

Comment: its a wrong work make it as a dict and add the dict to array and display in list after that you will get all data based on click

Comment: What programming language are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have an array with strings in it.

If so, you just need to split your strings.

objective-c code

```
NSArray *country = @[@"3;India", @"4;US", @"5;UK"];
NSString *countryStr = country[0];      // 3; India
NSArray *countryArr = [countryStr  componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
NSString *countryCode = countryArr.firstObject;  //3
NSString *countryName = countryArr.lastObject;   //India
NSLog(@"%@", countryCode);  //3
NSLog(@"%@", countryName);  //India
```

swift code

```
let country : NSArray = ["3;India", "4;US", "5;UK"]
let countryStr = country[0]
let countryArr : NSArray = countryStr.componentsSeparatedByString(";")
let countryCode = countryArr.firstObject
let countryName = countryArr.lastObject

if let countryCodePr = countryCode {
    print(countryCodePr)
}

if let countryNamePr = countryName {
    print(countryNamePr)
}
```

Comment: yes, it works for me by creating another array for countryName and countryCode.